# Order confirmation email not sending to admin or customer

Tags: orders, email, order-email, success-message

After placing an order the order success page shows but Order confirmation email is not sending to admin or customer. When i refresh cron.php on with my site url however, i receive mail.

Comment: Are you using any third party extensions to send your emails? Is it a new site or has this suddenly started happening? Theres a few things to consider, if using a third party extension, is it upto date? I've seen problems where the module hasn't been updated and has not changed to Magento's recent updates in which it utilises the cron and the core_email_quoue table. Also if your using Mandrill there have been some major changes recently which you might need to checkout, it is now a paid Mailchimp add on i believe.

Answer (score 0):

After magento 1.9 order confirmation mail send via cronjob , so you have to add cron.sh file located in root folder of magento installation, in your servers crontab.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up sender mail configs properly. If you are not using any mail server provider , the mails might be in junk or spam folder.